# Appcelerator Studio freezes when opening on OS X

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

When I open Appcelerator Studio on my Mac, I am greeted with a red screen asking for my email and password.

However, I cannot seem to edit either. The cursor just flashes on the password section and I cannot seem to edit anything, or press any buttons.

It seems like it's frozen as when I click "Appcelerator Studio" on the toolbar, nothing happens.

Note I have tried the following:

```
$ appc logout -D
$ appc login
$ sudo npm update -g
```

However, the same thing happens whenever I open the IDE.

Note that I am not having trouble logging in. It just won't even let me type anything.

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to re-install the Appc Studio because I had similar issue when I upgraded my Mac to Sierra. Studio was dead slow after that update.

Only solution was to clean install it as I already had Android SDK & XCode, so it didn't take much time.

After that, I always use `appc login` before even opening Studio & it has worked perfect since then.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue like this and as I remember, I installed the latest java since I tried NativeScript. When I checked my jdk I have jdk version > jdk1.8.0_91. I deleted the updated version and everything works fine.

```
$ ls ~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

to see what version of java you have. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you installed JDK 9.

Appcelerator Studio 4.10.0 is not supporting JDK 9 yet.Please downgrade it to JDK 1.8 to continue working with the studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with JDK 1.8.152/153 and JDK 9. Here is the direct link for JDK 1.8.131 - https://s3.amazonaws.com/titanium-studio/jdk/jdk-8u131-macosx-x64.dmg

You can follow the ticket for this issue here https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8878